# flutter_local_notifications does not show the notification(IOS only)

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-local-notification

i am beginner in flutter. I try to make an app which should notify users on scheduled time. I decided to use flutter_local_notification.

(I am trying to implement this only IOS as first step so that is why code blocks related with android commented in.)

```
class NotificationHelper {

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  initializeNotification() async {
    //tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
    IOSInitializationSettings(
        requestSoundPermission: false,
        requestBadgePermission: false,
        requestAlertPermission: false,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification
    );


    // final Android InitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    //     Android InitializationSettings("appicon");

      final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

  }
   onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
    // display a dialog with the notification details, tap ok to go to another page
    // showDialog(
    //   //context: context,
    //   builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
    //     title: Text(title),
    //     content: Text(body),
    //     actions: [
    //       CupertinoDialogAction(
    //         isDefaultAction: true,
    //         child: Text('Ok'),
    //         onPressed: () async {
    //           Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
    //           await Navigator.push(
    //             context,
    //             MaterialPageRoute(
    //               builder: (context) => SecondScreen(payload),
    //             ),
    //           );
    //         },
    //       )
    //     ],
    //   ),
    // );
  }
  Future selectNotification(String? payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      print('notification payload: $payload');
    } else {
      print("Notification Done");
    }
  }
  void requestIOSPermissions() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }
  displayNotification({required String title, required String body}) async {
    print("doing test");
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
        channelDescription: 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        12345,
        "A Notification From My Application",
        "This notification was sent using Flutter Local Notifcations Package",
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'data');
  }
}
```

and i call the initializeNotification() function on my `main.dart` like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  NotificationHelper().requestIOSPermissions();
  NotificationHelper().initializeNotification();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and after user logged in,
I just try to see my notification so i call displayNotification() on a button like this:

```
IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
      onPressed: () {
               NotificationHelper().displayNotification(title: 'title', body: 'hede');
                  },
        color: Colors.white,
        iconSize: 25,
        ),
```

and also i call this code in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
      }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

when application opens it successfully asks permissions for send notifications. After it allowed i just try to call displayNotification() but it doesn't work. I cannot see any notification on my simulator.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
```

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.3.3
```

What should i do ? Thank you for you all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think notifications doesn't work currently on İOS simulator. You should try real ios device